# Celery tasks sending to different queues is not working

Tags: django, redis, celery

My use case is to add use multiple queues for different tasks So that all upload_photos task is sent to one queue and upload_phone_number to another queue since upload task is a heavy task, I don't want an upload phone number to be affected by upload_photos,
even though I am using different queues, upload_phone_number task is waiting till the execution of upload photos. Is this the right way of writing multiple queues

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('fast', Exchange('fast'), routing_key='fast'),
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default')
)
```

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'upload_phone_number': {
        'exchange': 'fast'`
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'fast'
    },
    'upload_photos': {
        'exchange': 'default',
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'default'
    },
}
```

This is my celery task

```
@app.task(name="upload_phone_number")
def upload_photos():
```

```
@app.task(name="upload_phone_number")
def upload_phone():
```

Answer (score 0):

Celery from version 4.0 supports [priorities](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.2/userguide/routing.html#rabbitmq-message-priorities) through (RabbitMQ or Redis transport)

> ```
> from kombu import Exchange, Queue
>
> app.conf.task_queues = [
>     Queue('tasks', Exchange('tasks'), routing_key='tasks',
>           queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 10}),
>     Queue('different_tasks', Exchange('different_tasks'), routing_key='different_tasks',
>           queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 5}),
> ]
> ```

Regarding your solution:

Reason your example does not work is that you should spawn at-least 2 workers where one of them has only fast Que

```
celery worker -A myproject -Q fast
celery worker -A myproject -Q fast,slow
```